# How to search for text in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, document

I am using Firebase Storage to download a word document, so I can display it in my application using a UIWebView. This is the code for displaying the document:

```
@IBOutlet var Web_View: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let Bulletin = FIRStorage.storage()

    let Today = NSDateFormatter()
    Today.dateStyle = .LongStyle
    Today.timeStyle = .NoStyle

    let Ref_Bulletin = Bulletin.referenceForURL("gs://app.appspot.com/Bulletin/\(Today.stringFromDate(NSDate())).docx")

    Ref_Bulletin.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error Loading Today's Bulletin")
        } else {
            self.Web_View.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
            self.Web_View.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I need to do is search for certain words in this document but I have no idea what to do.

**Update:**

I am now saving the file to local storage:

```
var Bulletin = FIRStorage.storage()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let Date = NSDateFormatter()
    Date.dateStyle = .LongStyle
    Date.timeStyle = .NoStyle

    let Ref_Bulletin = Bulletin.referenceForURL("gs://app.appspot.com/Bulletin/\(Date.stringFromDate(NSDate())).docx")
    let localURL: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "file:///tmp/Bulletin/Today.docx")

    var error:NSError?

    let downloadTask = Ref_Bulletin.writeToFile(localURL) { (URL, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Error - " + error.debugDescription)
            } else {
                self.Web_View.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: localURL))
            }
        }

        downloadTask.observeStatus(.Progress) { snapshot in
            if let progress = snapshot.progress {
                let percentComplete = 100 * Double(progress.completedUnitCount) / Double(progress.totalUnitCount)
                self.Progress_Label.text = String(percentComplete.roundToPlaces(0)).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".0", withString: "") + "%"
            }
    }

}
```

Please not that I am currently experiencing a issue with this code, however this **should** work on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

first you convert your url into a string then you regex that string to find specific words you want to find

```
Ref_Bulletin.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print("Error Loading Today's Bulletin")
    } else {
        let string = try String(contentsOfURL: URL!)
        someRegexFunction(string)
        self.Web_View.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
        self.Web_View.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    }
}


func someRegexFunction(string:String) {}
```

Comment: let string = try String(contentsOfURL: URL!) does not give me the contents of the url, it just gives me the url.

Comment: wait let me double check my code. I think I might've given you the wrong one

Comment: is there by any way that you could convert this word document into just an html document? cause if you'd do that it'd probably solve your problem

Comment: also it's better to use Alamofire to download stuff from the internet

Comment: The problem is that my app requires docx or pdf, so I can't use html.

Comment: Also I have changed the downloading code, so now the document is saved in local storage.

Comment: could you update your question then so we could see the new code?

Comment: right now I have no idea what to do but I'm looking for a way to parse .docx files into a readable string you can regex